# How to get id for category so it can be added to href url to display category on next page

Tags: php

I have products displayed on my index page, I have a links which add id of product and title both from products table but I can also display category id from the products table but it's a int,

So can anyone advise how I grab the category name from category table and add to `<a href>` url,

```
  <a href="products.php?category=
```

so when I click on the link it takes me to the product but the breadcrumbs are populated as well!

My theory is to use a `$_get` category or something but given its my index page there's no `<a>` link to populate the url with the category id or something!

index.php

```
 <?php while($product = mysqli_fetch_assoc($top_components)) : ?>
      <div class="trendingproductsdiv">
        <div class="trendingproducts-img">
          <?php $photos = explode(',',$product['image']); ?>
          <a href="product_details.php?id=<?=$product['id'];?>&category=Components&title=<?=$product['title'];?>">
            <img src="<?= $photos[0]; ?>" alt="<?php echo $product['title']; ?>" class="group list-group-image" style="wdith:100px; height: 200px;">
          </a>
        </div>
       </div>
```

where it says &category=Components, I want that to represent the image I am clicking, i.e the images are generate dynamically based on the Top_components selected as 1 in my db, 
so if the product is Cat 6 (cases) and prod id = 1. the next page that loads will be for a Case product with id of 1.

I can get the product title and id to display but not the category, so that when the next page is view the breadcrumbs need to say Home>Cases> Product name.

UPDATE:

I got it working by doing this:

```
 <a href="product_details.php?id=<?=$product['id'];?>&cat=<?=$product['categories'];?>&title=<?=$product['title'];?>">
```

then my product_details.php page breadcrumb like this:

```
<a href="category.php?cat=<?php echo $breadcrumbs_cat['id'];?>"><?=$breadcrumbs_cat['category']; ?></a> &nbsp;
```

so it now looks like:

HOME>Cat ID> Product Name which is what I wanted,

Comment: Can't you get by $_REQUEST?

Comment: Do you have any example of how i could use $_request? As i am new to php!

Comment: Check the answer.

Comment: get your point Fred, but  Sarath Kumar helped me out, so surely my question was asked in the correct way to enable me to get an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`<a href="products.php?category=sales" alt="test">some button</a>`

The url will be `your-domain.com/products.php?category=sales`

```
<?php $catagory=$_REQUEST['category']; ?>
```

Here REQUEST must be in uppercase.

Comment: I got it but. I couldn't understand.You wants category from url. By using that your are going to change breadcrumbs that's what I got?

Comment: I have just updated my question. Thanks for your help anyways :)

Comment: That's great! you found the answer.